# How do you detect the largest set of parallel lines in an image?

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I have images with multiple line in them and I'm looking to detect the largest set of lines which are (approximately) parallel using Python and OpenCV. For example give:

[image]

The green lines are the best set:

[image]

Comment: Analyze the data returned from HoughLinesP() and or HoughLines().

Comment: please show your research effort and own thoughts on how to solve this. [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can follow the following steps

- Apply the Hough Line Transform to detect all line segments in the image.
- Group the line segments based on their orientation using a clustering
- Identify the largest cluster of lines. These will be the set of lines
  that are approximately parallel.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('UI5Mr.png')


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)


lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=10)


X = np.array([[x1, y1, x2, y2] for [[x1, y1, x2, y2]] in lines])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X[:, [2, 3]] - X[:, [0, 1]])
labels = kmeans.labels_
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_


counts = np.bincount(labels)
largest_cluster_idx = np.argmax(counts)
largest_cluster_mask = (labels == largest_cluster_idx)
largest_cluster_lines = X[largest_cluster_mask]


for [x1, y1, x2, y2] in largest_cluster_lines:
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)


plt.imshow(img)
```